# Unable to get .htaccess to do 301 redirects correctly in a Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I got a URL Canonicalization issue and I want to redirect https://www.barreau.co/ar to https://barreau.co/ar

Please note that the following .htaccess code redirects https://www.barreau.co/ to https://barreau.co/ perfectly, but not with the /ar or /en that the Laravel multilanguage applications add.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.barreau\.co\/ar$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/barreau\.co\/ar" [R=301,L]


# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

How can I make both https://www.barreau.co/ and https://www.barreau.co/ar redirect to non-www URLs correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's need to specify the locale imo.

Can you try this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried it in a local environment with a fresh Laravel installation. It works fine. Make sure you also have `mod_rewrite` enabled and to restart your apache after doing the change.